# Using Cron job with Codeigniter Result to this

Tags: cron, codeigniter-3

for some hours now i have been trying to use cron job to automatic upgrade user in my db by calling the the controller.

but this is what i keep getting on my email, i dont know where have gone wrong.

i will greately appreciate if anyone can please correct me

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent</p>
<p>Filename: Session/Session.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 143</p>


        <p>Backtrace:</p>


                        <p style="margin-left:10px">
                        File: /home/esclubso/public_html/application/core/My_Controller.php<br />
                        Line: 8<br />
                        Function: __construct                   </p>




                        <p style="margin-left:10px">
                        File: /home/esclubso/public_html/application/controllers/Welcome.php<br />
                        Line: 6<br />
                        Function: __construct                   </p>






                        <p style="margin-left:10px">
                        File: /home/esclubso/public_html/index.php<br />
                        Line: 316<br />
                        Function: require_once                  </p>
```

i have spent time deleting all with space from my controller yet nothing seem to be working and here is my controller

```
<?php
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public $layout;
    public $layout2;
    public $admin_layout;
    public $user_layout;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); // this is the line 8

        $this->layout   ='master';

        $this->user_layout  ='dashboard/user_dashboard/master';
        $this->admin_layout ='dashboard/admin_dashboard/master';
        $this->load->library('Session_checker');

        $this->load->model('Action');
        $this->load->model('Login_user');
        $this->load->model('Reaction');
        $this->load->model('Upgrade_account');
        $this->load->model('Manage_user');
    }
}
```

My welcome controler

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends My_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); // this is the line 6
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `My_controller` located?? Is it in the same folder or different folder??

Comment: What is in line number 143. Please provide us more code.

Comment: Yes the My_Controller is located inside the core folder. (application/core/My_Controller.php)

Comment: When I open the Session.php file inside system/libraries/session/session.php  the only thing in line 143 is session_start()